# redis - load from RDB and keep writing the AOF

Tags: redis, persistence

I'm working in combined mod - RDB + AOF.
I'm looking for a way to load after a restart from the RDB file - mainly for fast restarts.
On top of that, I want to continue writing the AOF.
Once I know there is a disaster, I will manually load from AOF.
This is my current config: (I know that `appendonly yes` is saying that the AOF will be loaded after restart, I'm looking for a wait load from RDB and keep writing the AOF.)

```
aof-use-rdb-preamble yes
aof-load-truncated yes
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
appendonly yes
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redis will always load the AOF if both are enabled, as AOF gives you better durability.

By using `aof-use-rdb-preamble` `yes`, you are already getting the best of both worlds. Your AOF is automatically rewritten every now and then automatically, with an RDB file first and a AOF tail. See [`redis.conf` L1157](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/6.0.6/redis.conf#L1157).

Since you want to have a predictable mean time to recovery (MTTR), you want to adjust the parameters for Automatic rewrite of the AOF, as described in [`redis.conf` LL113](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/6.0.6/redis.conf#L1113)

```
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
```

You can also manually trigger a AOF rewrite with the [`BGREWRITEAOF` command](https://redis.io/commands/BGREWRITEAOF)

`BGREWRITEAOF` would work even if `appendonly` is configured to `no`. However, note that every time you call `BGREWRITEAOF` you are getting pretty much an rdb file inside the appendonly.aof file.

Then, if `appendonly` is configured to `yes`, you also get an AOF tail (commands are appended to the appendonly.aof file).

`BGREWRITEAOF` and `BGSAVE` are expensive operations and will degrade the performance of your server while running. So I suggest you use only AOF, that already gives you log compaction either automatically or every time you run `BGREWRITEAOF`.

You can set `auto-aof-rewrite-percentage` to a low value, say 2 or 5 percent. Then you can test the MTTR (time it takes to restart) with both strategies. I am sure you'll find the difference is too small for it to make sense combining the two strategies separately (RDB and AOF). AOF already gives you RDB-inside if `aof-use-rdb-preamble` `yes`

Comment: Thanks, so having `BGREWRITEAOF` command in a corn mod, and `appendonly no` will cause the system to load from RDB and keep writing the AOF?

Comment: What you mean with a 'corn mod'?

Comment: let REDIS work totally with RDB. Then I want to save AOF every second as a background job. this way, my restarts will be very fast, and in case of disaster, I can work with the AOF to recover lost data.

Comment: Updated answer per your comment